# Advancing a pseudo-counter in an align environment

Tags: align, expansion, grouping

I'm getting some strange results I don't really understand with the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\initializecount{\def\aecnt{0}}
\newcommand\aenextify{%%
  \pgfmathparse{int(\aecnt+1)}%%
  \xdef\aecnt{\pgfmathresult}%%
  \typeout{>> \aecnt}%%
}

\begin{document}

\initializecount
Current: \aecnt
\begin{align*}
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following

> [image]

It's as if each `\aenextify` command is being expanded once when the `align*` environment is first parsed and then again as each line of the environment is expanded.  What I would like to do is start the *counter* at zero and after each line of the `align*` environment, advance this counter.

I tried inserting a `\noexpand`, but then the pseudo-counters are completely ignored or had no noticeable effect.  (In this MWE, the `\noexpand` itself just seems to be ignored.)

```
\aecnt && \aecnt\\\noexpand\aenextify
```

Please note that I'm not interested in actually using LaTeX's native counters, this is just a MWE that illustrates my problem.  If you can get this MWE to work or explain why it's failing without resorting to using *real* counters, then I'll be very appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some AMS environments such as `align` process the contents twice, once in a "measuring" phase and then "for real". You want to step the counter only once.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\initializecount{\def\aecnt{0}}
\newcommand\aenextify{%%
\unless\ifmeasuring@%
  \xdef\aecnt{\the\numexpr\aecnt+1}%%
  \typeout{>> \aecnt}%%
\fi  
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\initializecount
Current: \aecnt
\begin{align*}
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
  \aecnt && \aecnt\\\aenextify
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. You do not need `pgf` to increase the number, but the code of course also works with `pgf`.

Comment: There's various other things going on in the original document where I was using `pgfmath`.  I wasn't sure whether the problem might be there.  Thank you for this answer.

Comment: @A.Ellett I see. Yes, that makes sense. To the best of my knowledge the problem is not related to `pgf` but only to the "measuring problem". And you're welcome!

Comment: Your solution works well.